Issue with transitioning code for computing stellar orbit around a black hole to solve_ivp in Python
I've been working on a Python code to compute the orbit of a star around a black hole at the center of our Galaxy. The code includes an implementation of a gaseous disc with hydrodynamical drag force considered alongside the gravitational interaction. Initially, I implemented a 4th order Runge-Kutta method to solve the differential equations governing the motion. However, I wanted to enhance the code's efficiency and accuracy by leveraging the solve_ivp function from the SciPy library.
According to my knowledge, the Runge-Kutta method works just fine. However, I was not able to recieve the right results with the solve_ivp "DOP853".
Here is the code with DOP853 implementation:
################################################### Imports section #########################################################
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.constants import G, parsec, year, c
from astropy.constants import M_sun
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp


# Computing the velocity components of the gaseous disk
def gas_velocity_keplerian_disc(x, y):

    """
    Computes the gas velocity components in Keplerian motion around the black hole.
    Assumes the gas follows a circular orbit in the x-y plane.
    :param x, y: position of the star from the black hole in the x-y plane [m]
    :param m_bh: mass of the black hole [kg]
    :return: velocity components (vx_gas, vy_gas) in the x-y plane [m/s]
    """

    dist = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)

    # Magnitude of velocity for a gas particle in a circular orbit
    v_gas_mag = np.sqrt(G * m_bh / dist)

    # Components of velocity assuming the gas moves in a circular orbit in the x-y plane
    vx_gas = -y / dist * v_gas_mag
    vy_gas = x / dist * v_gas_mag

    return vx_gas, vy_gas

# Function to calculate acceleration
def acceleration(t, state, m, c_d, R, ro, h, R_disc):
    x, y, z, vx, vy, vz = state

    dist = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)

    ax_grav = -G * m_bh * x / dist**3
    ay_grav = -G * m_bh * y / dist**3
    az_grav = -G * m_bh * z / dist**3

    # Check if z is close to +- h/2
    if -h/2 < z and z < h/2:
        # Hydrodynamical drag force components
        vx_gas, vy_gas = gas_velocity_keplerian_disc(x, y)

        vx_rel = vx - vx_gas
        vy_rel = vy - vy_gas
        vz_rel = vz

        v_rel_mag = np.sqrt(vx_rel**2 + vy_rel**2 + vz_rel**2)

        ax_drag = -0.5 * c_d * ro0 * np.pi * R**2 * v_rel_mag * vx_rel / m
        ay_drag = -0.5 * c_d * ro0 * np.pi * R**2 * v_rel_mag * vy_rel / m
        az_drag = -0.5 * c_d * ro0 * np.pi * R**2 * v_rel_mag * vz_rel / m
        print("Hydrodynamic drag force applied.")

    else:
        ax_drag, ay_drag, az_drag = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
        print("Hydrodynamic drag force not applied.")

    # Total acceleration
    ax = ax_grav + ax_drag
    ay = ay_grav + ay_drag
    az = az_grav + az_drag

    return [vx, vy, vz, ax, ay, az]

# Event function to terminate integration when the distance from the black hole falls below 100 gravitational radii
def event(t, state, m, c_d, R, ro, h, R_disc):
    x, y, z, vx, vy, vz = state

    distance_from_bh = np.sqrt(x**2 + y**2 + z**2)
    return distance_from_bh - 100 * r_grav

event.terminal = True  # Terminate integration when the event is triggered
event.direction = -1   # Trigger the event only when crossing from positive to negative

############################################# Black hole's information section ##############################################
# Black hole info (in SI units)
m_bh = 4.31e6 * M_sun.value  # Mass of the black hole in kg
x_bh, y_bh, z_bh = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0
vx_bh, vy_bh, vz_bh = 0.0, 0.0, 0.0

############################################## Additional parameters definition #############################################
r_grav = (G * m_bh) / c**2
r_bondi = (2 * G * m_bh) / c**2

################################################# Initial conditions ########################################################
# Time range
tstart, tstop = 2000 * year, 2200 * year  # Integration time range in years
t_span = (tstart, tstop)
t_eval = np.linspace(tstart, tstop, 1000)

# Initial conditions of a star (in meters and km/s)
initial_state = np.array([-129598458359999.98, -117255748040000.0, 253025561560000.03,
                          -1325901.2, 723308.2, -449334.5])

#initial_state = np.array([1e14, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1e6, 0.0])

# Disk information
c_d = 1
ro0 = 1e-14  #default 1e-11!!!
h = 2e20
R_disc = 1e20
# Shakura-Sunyaev disk parameters
alpha = 0.3  # typical value for the viscosity parameter
M_dot = 1e-6 * M_sun.value / year  # mass accretion rate per year

# Orbiting object info (dust particle)
# R = 696340e3  # Radius of star in meters
R = 2.0   # Radius of dust particle in meters
m = 0.028    # Mass of the dust particle in kg

# Solve the initial value problem with event function
sol = solve_ivp(acceleration, t_span, initial_state, method='DOP853',
                rtol=1e-10, atol=1e-10, args=(m, c_d, R, ro0, h, R_disc), events=event)

This is the expected result (my result from 4th order Runge Kutta code)
expected_rk4_result
And this is the result I'm getting with the DOP853 code:
dop853_result
Clearly, the spiraling is not physically correct.
Can anyone see an error in my implementation and can correct it? Thank you all!

Can we see the version of your code that you claim "works", including the initial condition. Note also that we need to be able to run your code. It's not specifically "DOP853" that produces the result: any of the methods in solve_ivp will do the same. It's very difficult to check your equations as you are mixing length units (km in velocity and m in position). If you use inconsistent units then v will NOT be the time derivative of x, so your derivative routine is screwed.

Actually, I think your solve_ivp/DOP853 solution is perfectly reasonable. Gravity in this instance will pull the star down. Drag will pull the path TOWARD the circular path of the accretion disk, but not hold it there. If you want to reduce the spiralling outward then increase the drag, either by increasing the drag coefficient c_d or the density of gas ro0. Your plot will also look more realistic if you use equal aspect ratios on all three axes.
